# Using Case in select statement with NSFetchRequest

Tags: ios, sql, core-data, nsfetchrequest

Is there any way of using `CASE` statement in `SQL SELECT` using `NSFetchRequest`?

```
        @[
        [NSString stringWithFormat:@"CASE %@ WHEN %@ THEN 1 WHEN %@ THEN 2 WHEN %@ THEN 3 WHEN %@ THEN 4 ELSE 0 END",
         COLUMN_ENUM,
         INTEGER_ENUM1,
         INTEGER_ENUM2,
         INTEGER_ENUM3,
         INTEGER_ENUM4]
    ]
```

Where enums contains column name and integers.

I need this, because one column contains string, but I have to order by this column (not alphabetically), and I can't use `SortDescriptor` with comparator (`NSFetechedResultsController` not supporting it).

Any idea how can I achieve this?

Comment: Hey your question is unclear. Please try to explain better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A sort descriptor for a (SQL based) Core Data fetch request can only use *persistent properties* of the entity and only a limited set of sort selectors (`compare:`, `caseInsensitiveCompare:`, `localizedCompare:`, `localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:`, and `localizedStandardCompare:`). You cannot use Objective-C based comparators or arbitrary
SQL expressions.

`localizedStandardCompare:` is useful if you have strings containing numbers that should be sorted
according to their numerical value.

(See ["Fetch Predicates and Sort Descriptors"](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdPersistentStores.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002875-SW11)
in the "Core Data Programming Guide" for more information.)

So if none of the supported sort selectors provides the ordering that you want, you will
have to add an additional attribute just for ordering the objects.